# python tkinter entry can not get value from askdirectory

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a tkinter program of pop new windows to do something.when I ran it,there are two problems.The first problem is poping two windows when click "1、reset chanel".I checked over and over,but the problem is still over there.The second problem is about the 'Entry' value.I want it to show the askdirectory value.Whatever I done,it is still empty.
Here is the code,any help is appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, dialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter.messagebox import *

class SgyChan(tk.Toplevel):
   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup_UI()
        
    def open_bigspsfile(self):
        self.filebig_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.bigpath.set(self.filebig_path)
        print(self.filebig_path)

    def open_litspsfile(self):
        self.filelit_path = askdirectory() #
        self.litpath.set(self.filelit_path)
        print(self.filelit_path)

    def getValueBig(self):
        self.filebig_path=self.entry1.get()
        return self.filebig_path
    def getValueLit(self):
        self.filelit_path=self.entry2.get()
        return self.filelit_path

    def mat_file(self):
        spspath=self.getValueBig()
        watchdir=self.getValueLit()
        print('working......')
    def setup_UI(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('500x100+600+300')
        root.title('sgy change chan')
        self.bigpath= tk.StringVar()
        self.litpath= tk.StringVar()
        
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text="1、sps file:")
        label2 = tk.Label(root, text="2、sgy :")
        label1.grid(row=0)
        label2.grid(row=1)
        
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(root,width=40,textvariable = self.bigpath)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=40,textvariable = self.litpath)
        
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        buttonForFile = tk.Button(root, text="browser files", command=self.open_bigspsfile)
        buttonRun = tk.Button(root, text="browser directory", command=self.open_litspsfile)
        buttonForFile.grid(row=0, column=2)
        buttonRun.grid(row=1, column=2)
        buttonMatch = tk.Button(root, text="3、data process", command=self.mat_file)
        buttonMatch.grid(row=4, column=1)

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('500x145+400+100')
        self.title('sgy tools')
        self.setupUI()
    def setupUI(self):
        
        row1 = tk.Frame(self)
        row1.pack(fill="x")

        buttonForFile = tk.Button(row1, text="1、reset chanel", command=SgyChan)
        buttonForFile.grid(row=0, column=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = MyApp()
  app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `SgyChan` is a subclass of `Toplevel`, so it *is* a window - but you never use that window; instead you create a second instance of `Tk()` and put widgets into that instead.  Multiple instances of `Tk` is such a problematic thing to do that I'm not going to look at the code further; I will simply assume that this is the root cause of all problems.

Comment: got the point.this is the first time to use class,problem solved.